# if (indata[0] == '10') does not work

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, arduino

I have been working on some arduino code for a few days and I have ran into this problem. I need to check if inData is equal to a number up to 150 but when I get in the double and triple digits it stops working. Here is the code I am using. it takes number inputs from a keypad that is setup to send its numbers to the arduino's serial RX pin.

Too long to put it here so i put it on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/n7CqwuX8).

```
char inData[20]; // Allocate some space for the string
if (inData[0] == '10') {
// Code snipped for brevity
}
```

Comment: A lot of people (me included) won't go "off site" to look at your code. What type is `indata`?

Comment: `'10'` is _not_ a character.

Comment: while (Serial.available()) {
        delay(10);
        char c = Serial.read(); 
        if (c == ',') {break;} 
        readString += c;
                
    if (readString == "#") {
    look();
    readString="";
    break;
    }
        
inData[index] = c;
index++; 
inData[index] = '\0';

Comment: @timrau: no, but it is a short.  This is the fastest and simplest way to compare 2 chars: \*(WORD\*)inData == '01'.  I'm assuming intel architecture so you have to compensate for endianess by reversing the digits of the short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues.

First, use the `if..then..else` construct or a switch for the several `if..then` statements.

And, when you do a comparison to a char `10` is two char values so a simple == won't work.

You could convert it to an integer first, using `atoi` and then do a comparison, or you can look at `if (inData[0] == '1' && inData[1] == '0')` would do what you want.

**UPDATE:**

I would ensure that each part of inData is set to zero first, not '0'.

Then use a switch, such as something like this:

```
switch(inData[0]) {
  case '1':
    switch(inData[1]) {
       case 0:
         // This would be '1'
         break;
       case '0':
         // This will be 10
         break;
    }
    break;
  case '2':
     break;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, just use as an example.

Comment: i just added 'if (inData[0] == '1' && inData[1] == '0')' to my code to use that but when i enter 10 it just shows up as 1.

Comment: when i enter 10 it shows 1 than 10 so it is still picking up the 1

Comment: You need to reverse the order, and use the if..then..else, so look for the larger numbers before the smaller.

Comment: could you give me a example on using if...then...else with this?

Comment: I prefer the switch for this, so I gave a rough example.

Comment: This is the fastest and simplest way to compare 2 chars: \*(WORD\*)inData == '01'.  I'm assuming intel architecture so you have to compensate for endianess by reversing the digits of the short.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `inData`, a `char` array, is a C-style, `'\0'` terminated string. Then what you should do is calling `strcmp()` instead of comparing the 1<sup>st</sup> character only.

```
#include <cstring>

if (std::strcmp(inData, "1") == 0) {
}
else if (std::strcmp(inData, "2") == 0) {
}
//...
else if (std::strcmp(inData, "10") == 0) {
}
```

Please be aware of the difference between `''` quoted character literal and `""` quoted string literal.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more effective to turn this into an int, then just compare, rather than doing a strcmp several times?

Comment: @JamesBlack Good point. `atoi()` or `sscanf()` + `switch`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `std::string` if this is C++

```
std::string inData; // Allocate some space for the string

// Replace this:
// inData[index] = c;
// index++;
// inData[index] = '\0';   

// with
inData += c;

if (inData == "10") {   // Test for a specific string.
```

Comment: my code is for the arduinoIDE

Comment: @user3732307: So the question is not about C++ then? Or the IDE does not support the standard library?

Comment: i dont know what code arduino comes from but i know that std::string inData; dose not work in it.

Comment: @user3732307: Did you `#include <string>` at the top of the file?

Comment: idk but i know that this wont work for me with this but thank you.